# ¿Cómo se usa mysql.connector?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, mysqlconnector

Para realizar la conexión con la base de datos de `mysql`, necesito un usuario, una contraseña y poner el nombre de la base de datos.

```
import mysql.connector
conexion = mysql.connector.connect("user='', password='', host='localhost', database=''")
```

Acabo de instalar mysql para python (`sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector`), por lo que supongo que no tego ningún nombre de usuario ni contraseña.

Necesito crear un usuario, **¿Como puedo crear un usuario, y una contraseña?** Y, ¿**Como puedo interactuar directamente con la base de datos sin usar un script python?** Un sitio donde ingresar código SQL. Gracias.

Comment: LO que bajaste solo fue el driver, debes tener ya el server de mysql instalado usa las credenciales de acceso de ese server

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comenta el amigo Alfredo Paz es cierto, lo que tienes que indicar son el nombre de usuario y la contraseña de una base de datos que ya tengas instalada, por ejemplo de MySQL, MariaDB o cualquier otra BBDD que hay en el mercado. Si no tienes ninguna base de datos no vas a poder conectarte.

Para instalar por ejemplo MariaDB puedes utilizar el siguiente código:

`sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client`

Despues de instalar tu base de datos en el campo `database=''` tienes que especificar el nombre de esta, y si por casualidad quieres utilizar una base de datos que no está en tu PC tendrías que poner la url en el campo `host=''`